# python import not working from one module to another

Tags: python

I have a below structure
[image]

in migrations/env.py file I am trying to import `from database import *`
but it shows `no module name database` 
I tried `from ..database imprt *` and adding file in `pythonpath` also but no luck :(

Comment: In which directory are you invoking the interpreter?

Comment: Wich python version are you using?

Comment: @RodrigoLópez I am using python 3.6

Answer (score 2):

Your directory structure looks a bit suspicious to me. The `alembic.ini` shouldn't normally be part of the package (and setuptools won't by default pick it up when packaging). I think this would better be placed into the project-root.

Something like this would be more standard:

`├── alembic.ini
├── migrations
│   ├── env.py
│   ├── script.py.mako
│   └── versions
│   └── ...
├── package_name
│   └── database
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── ...
│       └── models
│           └── __init__.py
│           └── ...
├── README.md
└── setup.py
└── ...`

Now, this alone would not make `database` available from `env.py`. For this to work you have to somehow make your package discoverable. Usually this would be done by installing `package_name` into some virtualenv. In that environment you could then use `from package_name.database import *` in your `env.py`.

Comment: I wanted to say that, but the way I see this is that database *has* `__init__.py`

Comment: he has __init in database

Comment: @deets it doesn't, the submodule `models` does, but `database` does not

Comment: no, models is > (closed arrow, so the folder contents are not visible for us)

Comment: @deets Ah, you're right. the rest still applies though :). I've updated the answer accordingly, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Migrations needs to know where to import from, they either belong to the same package:

A:

migrations

database

**init**.py

And then in migrations:

from A.database.whatever import whatever else

Or you install them as packages separatedly inside your virtualenv:
And then each of them is dependent on the other, but because they are installed they can be invoked:

database/setup.py
migrations/setup.py

Then both are installed and migrations/env.py can call the installed package database